# Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines - can they pull a script from a repo?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my graphical version of a release, I am connecting to an "Azure Repo" to pull in a script from it, not a BUILD artifact

Is this possible to do in YAML pipelines? So far it is very unclear, thanks in advance

The repo has a lot of scripts in it, so it doesn't need building or packaging up as a zip/drop package.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah sorry,my bad. Yes it is possible. Following [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema)

If your pipeline has templates in another repository, or if you want to use multi-repo checkout with a repository that requires a service connection, you must let the system know about that repository. The repository keyword lets you specify an external repository.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: string  # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
    type: enum  # see the following "Type" topic
    name: string  # repository name (format depends on `type`)
    ref: string  # ref name to use; defaults to 'refs/heads/master'
    endpoint: string  # name of the service connection to use (for types that aren't Azure Repos)
```

Comment: For YAML tasks?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 2):

A resource is any external service that is consumed as part of your pipeline. An example of a resource is another CI/CD pipeline that produces:

```
resources:
  pipelines: [ pipeline ]
  repositories: [ repository ]
  containers: [ container ]
```

- Artifacts like Azure Pipelines or Jenkins.
- Code repositories like GitHub, [**Azure Repos**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource), or Git.
- Container-image registries like Azure Container Registry or Docker
  hub.

Resources in YAML represent sources of pipelines, containers, repositories, and types. For more information on Resources, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-repositories).

Answer (score 0):

@Hugh Lin - MSFT
@Krzysztof Madej

My Azure DevOps GIT repo called "AZDO_Scripts" (all part of the same project) and has a structure like this...

**/Scripts/AzureCLI/ResourceGroup/Provision_ResourceGroup_withTags.ps1**

My YAML is like this now...

```
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)-$(SourceBranchName)

trigger:
- master

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: commonscripts
    type: git
    name: AZDO_Scripts

stages:
- stage: Test
  variables:
    - name: resourcegroup
      value: 'rg-testthescript'
    - name: location
      value: 'WestEurope'
    - name: environmenttag
      value: 'Test'
  jobs:
    - job : TestJob
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'My-Azure-Sub-ServiceConnection'
          scriptType: 'ps'
          scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
          scriptPath: 'Scripts/AzureCLI/ResourceGroup/Provision_ResourceGroup_withTags.ps1@commonscripts'
          arguments: '-resourcegroup $(resourcegroup) -location $(location) -environmenttag $(environmenttag)'
```

What do I need to do in the scriptPath: statement to reference that script? (2nd line from the bottom)

```
scriptPath: 'Scripts/AzureCLI/ResourceGroup/Provision_ResourceGroup_withTags.ps1@commonscripts'
```

Comment: Just like this `scriptPath: Scripts/AzureCLI/ResourceGroup/Provision_ResourceGroup_withTags.ps1` In addition, you can select the script path in the azure cli task in classic editor and click [View YAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NjDS.png) to generate yaml script for comparison.